# Get page name instead of page number with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/02/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/) to create a simple page loading contents with AJAX. I'm working with AJAX and PHP, the problem is that in the tutorial the dude is using page names like "page1, page2, page3, etc". I don't want to do this, I want to use the name of the actual page instead of that, ex. "products,about, etc". I've been trying to work with the code on the load.php but I get this notice everytime and the page won't load; **Notice: Undefined index: page in "MY TEST SITE" on line 2 and 3**

This is load.php

```
<?php
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];
if(file_exists('pages/page'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page'.$page.'.html');
else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

And the Javascript file

```
$(function() {
    $('header nav a').click(function() {
        var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
        var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#page', '');
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load.php",
                data: 'page='+$pageRoot,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){
                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {
                    $('#main-content').html(msg);
                    $('#main-content section').hide().fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
switch (hash) {
    case 'products' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'about' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'storelocator' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'media' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'faq' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
    case 'contact' :
        $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
        break;
}
});
```

**EDIT**
Menu HTML

```
  <a href="#products" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">products</a>
  <a href="#about" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">about</a>
  <a href="#storelocator" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">store locator</a>
  <a href="#media" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">media</a>
  <a href="#faq" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">faq</a>
  <a href="#contact" class="w-nav-link nav-link" data-overlay-trigger="overlay">contact</a>
```

The menu also opens an overlay where the content is displayed.

What's a possible solution?

Comment: Have you made changes in the HTML as well? add your HTML code as well

Comment: HTML added @codeHeart

Comment: There is no `#page` in your href and why are you trying to set `$_POST['page']` to an integer?

Comment: Quite honestly I don't see why you even need php for this if all you are doing is pulling in static html files

Comment: btw, `if(!isset($_POST['page'])) die("0");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So person in the tutorial is doing this

`var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#page', '');`

Basically they are removing `#page` from `#page1`, `#page2` and so on.. So that they are only left with the number 1, 2 so on, and they send over the page number to the server like

`data: 'page='+$pageRoot, // here $pageRoot will be a number`

You want to send the page name directly.

So you will change the line to be

`var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#', '');`

now $pageRoot will have your pagename like 'products'

Also as a side note, when you work through this code, keep the Developer tools open on your browser and see what was the request that was sent in the network panel

Comment: Ohhh, ok, so now I understand the code. This helped, thanks.